# Why isn't my form working correctly when trying to post something using Ajax and an external PHP file, which is receiving two strings?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So basically I'm trying to use Ajax to work with a PHP file and post both inputs (fullname and phonenumber), but it doesn't seem to be working when I try and click the submit button it only refreshes.

Here's my code, it's all on the HTML file:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function validateForm () {
var x=document.forms["myForm"] ["fullname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert ("First name must be filled out");
return false;
}
var x=document.forms["myForm"] ["phonenumber"].value;
if (x=null || x=="")
{
alert ("Please enter a phone number");
return false;
}
function isNumberKey(evt) {
var e = evt || window.event; //window.event is safer,
var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 47 || charCode > 57))
return false;
if (e.shiftKey) return false;
return true;
}
</script>
<script>
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://www.bmoseley.com/ajax/addrecord.php",
data: "fullname=" + fullname + "&phonenumber=" + phonenumber,
success: function(){
alert("Name and phone number added successfully!");
}
});
$("#displayInfo").load("http://www.bmoseley.com/ajax/listrecords.php");  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="info">
<form name="myForm" action="#" onSubmit="return validateForm ()">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><input id="fullname" name="fullname" maxlength="50" type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Name" action="#"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="Phone Number"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<div id="displayInfo">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#displayInfo").load("http://www.bmoseley.com/ajax/listrecords.php");
});
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the messy code. Hope someone can help!

Comment: Is the AJAX request being sent? Check in console.

Comment: @SandeepNayak I believe not, it says "unexpected end of input" and "unexpected token }" After deleting the extra } now it says "fullname is not defined"

Comment: Just running your code gave me Two errors: `SyntaxError: missing } after function body` @line 28 and `SyntaxError: syntax error }` @line40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sent the ajax request on the form submit, your code does it while page is loading.

Remove the inline submit handler `onSubmit="return validateForm ()"` and try

```
jQuery(function () {
    //register a form submit event handler
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        //stop the default form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        //validations, use jQuery selectors to get the input elements
        var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
        if (fullname == '') {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return;
        }
        var phonenumber = $('#phonenumber').val();
        if (phonenumber == '') {
            alert("Please enter a phone number");
            return;
        }

        //if validations are successful then send the ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.bmoseley.com/ajax/addrecord.php",
            data: "fullname=" + fullname + "&phonenumber=" + phonenumber,
            success: function () {
                alert("Name and phone number added successfully!");
            }
        }).always(function () {
            //once ajax request is completed reload the list
            $("#displayInfo").load("http://www.bmoseley.com/ajax/listrecords.php");
        });
    })
})

function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event; //window.event is safer,
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 47 || charCode > 57)) return false;
    if (e.shiftKey) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but now in the console it mentions "query is not defined"

Comment: Include the library in your html file like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Sorry I didn't delete the other part. Now it's successful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that @Arun has already the answer on your question only an additional information to you because I saw your comment on his answer.

If the console says `jquery is not defined` maybe you did not include the library on your file, you may do it so by

```
//referencing it on google_codes like
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


//or downloading the framework at [jquery][1] and include to your file like
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "path where you paset the downloaded file"></script>
```

hope it hepls :)

Comment: Thanks! I believe it had to do with a piece of code I forgot to delete when overwriting it. Always good to know though.